# Python: How do I uppercase the complete word "i" only?

Tags: python

So, I'm trying to get the complete word "i" capitalized only, without capitalizing every other words with "i" in it. For example, in this assignment I'm working on, the program asks the user to enter a sentence that is ran together but the first character of each word is capitalized. Say if the user input was "IHaveAnIntegerI". What I have so far prints out "I have an Integer I". What I want is "I have an integer I". Thanks.

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.

Comment: "What I have so far [does the wrong thing]" My best guess is that there is something wrong with what you have so far. If you wish for us to help you fix what you have so far, it would be very helpful if you could actually show it to us.

Answer (score 1):

For string problems involving "words", the simplest solution is usually a regular expression, as `\b` can be used to match word boundaries. So the regular expression `\bi\b` matches the letter `i` if and only if it is on its own as a word.

```py
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\bi\b', 'I', 'i did it, i did it!')
'I did it, I did it!'
```

Note that this is only an approximation of what counts as a "word" in natural language; for example, it will capitalise the abbreviation `i.e.` incorrectly, and it will capitalise the word `i've` correctly but by coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way of doing it:

```
i_values = {'i', "i'"}

text_example = "hello i am i'm i am i m not"

result = []
for word in text_example.split():
    result.append(word.capitalize() if word.lower() in i_values else word)

result = ' '.join(result)

print(result)
# hello I am I'm I am I m not
```

Comment: I'm, I'd, I'll, I've

Comment: I edited the post now it should work for any ```'i'``` or ```"i'"```, if you face any new problem you can just update the set ```i_values```

Answer (score -1):

It might help:

> The capitalize() method returns a string where the first character is upper case.

So:

```
txt = "I Have An Integer I"

x = txt.capitalize()

print (x)
```

Yields:

```
I have an integer i
```

Comment: OP wants `"I have an integer I"`. At the end of your suggestion they're still stuck with two lowercase `i` out of which only one needs to be capitalized. Also you can't assume the string will always start with `I`

Comment: @PranavHosangadi According to the OP, *What I have so far prints out "I have an Integer I"*, so the question is not about how to add the spaces - they can already do that.

Comment: @kaya3 sure, but this answer doesn't work because of the assumption that the first character needs to be capitalized and everything else lowercased, which is not the case.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I responded to your comment before you edited it.

Comment: @kaya3 Having two lowercase `I`s and not knowing which one to capitalize isn't any better than having two uppercase `I`s. That's what I intended my comment to mean.